# Correct way in getting data from the database in 2-3 tables in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

How do you get all the data from the database in 2-3 tables in CodeIgniter?
I'm really having problem on this one. And after I fetch the data and load it in a certain view or page, would i still be able to use the data when a certain DIV of the page would be changed into another DIV by jQuery?
Btw Im new to codeigniter so please help. Thanks.

here is my code in the CONTROLLER

```
 public function assets(){
        if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
        $this->load->model('asset_model');
        $this->data['main'] = $this->asset_model->get_all();
        $this->load->view('imports/header');
        $this->load->view('assets',$this->data);
        } else {
            redirect('main/restricted');
        }
    }
```

in the MODEL

```
class Asset_model extends CI_Model{

public function get_all(){
     $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('computer c'); 
        $this->db->join('hardware h', 'h.hw_comp_id=c.comp_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('software s', 's.sw_comp_id=c.comp_id', 'left');
        $this->db->order_by('c.comp_id','asc');         
        $query = $this->db->get(); 
        if($query->num_rows() != 0)
        {
            return $query->result_array();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

}
}
```

in the VIEW

```
 foreach ($main as $computer){
      $comp_id = $asset['comp_id'];
      $comp_num = $asset['comp_num'];
      $location = $asset['location'];
      $status = $asset['status'];

  ?>


  <center><i class="huge desktop icon""></i><h3>Computers</h3>
  <button class="ui basic button"> 
  <center><i class="huge desktop icon"></i></i><p><p> PC-01</p></p>
  </button>

  <?php } ?>
```

I got an error in the viewing part in Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Need to narrow this down into smaller issues. What is working and what isn't?

Comment: @charlietfl the foreach in the view is not working. but i just wanna also know if my other codes are correct.

Comment: please help me.. the data i passed from the controller to the view wont display!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view, before your foreach loop put in the following code :

```
if($main === false) {
   printf('No data returned from model');
} else {
    foreach ($main......)
```

This will tell you if your model is correctly pulling the data or on.